# compileStatement gives me: 'Cannot bind argument at index 0 because the index is out of range. The statement has 1 parameters.'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

What is wrong with this code? I get this error:

> Cannot bind argument at index 0 because the index is out of range.
> The statement has 1 parameters.

This is my code:

```
fun updateShowOnMapAllRows(database: GeneratedDatabase, showOnMap: Boolean) {
    val stmt = database.compileStatement("update Conversation set showOnMap = ?")
    assert(database.inTransaction())

    val val0 = if (showOnMap) { 1L } else { 0L }
    
    // Error happens here
    stmt.bindLong(0, val0)

    stmt.execute()
}
```

Comment: The 1st argument of `bindLong()` is a 1-based index: `stmt.bindLong(1, val0)`